# sort function within function not working when using function variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, sorting

I'm having a function sort some json based on the object property. It works when I hard code the property into the sort function, but when it tries to pull it dynamically from the display_list function (sortCat), it doesn't work. resultDeals is the json

```
function display_list(sortCat) {
if (resultDeals !== undefined) {
    resultDeals.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.sortCat - b.sortCat;
    });
    for(i = 0; i < resultDeals.length; i++) {
        where sorted data is printed
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try a[sortCat] and b[sortCat]

Comment: unsure whether you meant to write `a[sortCat]`, `a.sortCat` is not using the argument at all, it is accessing a property called "sortCat".

Comment: a[sortCat] and the like worked. Thank you!!!